# CSS only shows correctly on index page. Ruby On Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am new to Ruby On Rails and am trying to get a css template to work for a project. It works fine on my index page but on every other page it doesn't seem to be getting the complete layout from the application.html.haml file.

If I use the link to include the css in the page it will only add font changes and color changes, but none of the actual layout changes ie. tables, formatting and such.

```
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'style'
```

I'm not to sure where to troubleshoot now since it's only grabbing half my styles from the style sheet.

```
!!! 5
%html
  %head
    %title HELPDESK   
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %link{:href => "style.css", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/

  %body
    %h1.title HELPDESK
    #main
      - if flash[:notice]
        #notice.message= flash[:notice]
      - elsif flash[:warning]
        #warning.message= flash[:warning]

      = yield
```

If it's any help, I can rename my other pages to index.html.haml and the css loads perfectly fine, so the pages are written correctly I just have an error with the way Rails loads stylesheets or an error with a route.

tl:dr everything in my Rails app after **site.com/questions/** does not load with the correct stylesheet, while **site.com/questions** loads perfectly fine.

Thanks!

### Alright, for anyone that reads this later, I fixed the problem. I needed to make the link in the application.html.haml file (listed above) point to ../style.css instead of style.css

Comment: Are you putting the stylesheet line in the layout file?

Comment: You can inspect in the browser console if all the style files you expect are being written in the page.

Comment: The Stylsheet line is what I can add to an individual page to use the stylesheet, but it only gets the parts like fonts, text color and size etc. not the acctual page formatting that I need. I've been taking a look at it in web developer and it doesnt seem to be loading the correct parts of the page. But it is grabbing the right stysheet and making the correct links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I needed to make the link in the application.html.haml file (listed above) point to ../style.css instead of style.css